# Bindings of MEX Endpoint over TCP with an IIS-hosted WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I have several WCFs exposing Mex end point over IIS. I would like to change inactivetimeout value to 20 minutes and some other settings also. Hence added binding configuration to service config file.
The problem is that when I specify bindingConfiguration="MyConfig", I get the below error

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://endpointaddress. If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error

My service config looks like below. I am using wcf test client to test the service. Any information on how to resolve would be greatly appreciated.

```
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyConfig"  contract="IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="MyConfig" >
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"
          enabled="false" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```